# Rails 4: Link_to tag not creating appropriate html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Bootstrap's tooltip to show glyphicons.

Hardcoded, this works as expected

```
    <%= link_to "<h2>test</h2>",
                        '#',
                        class: "tag-tooltip",
                        :data => {:toggle=>"tooltip"},
                        'data-original-title' => 
    "<i class=\"icon-off icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-info-sign icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-ban-circle icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-warning-sign icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-remove icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-refresh icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-download-alt icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-list-alt icon-white\"></i> = SomeText
    <i class=\"icon-ok icon-white\"></i> = SomeText",
                        'data-placement' => 'top' %>
```

Now I'll use a helper method to achieve the same thing.

```
<%= link_to 'First', '#', class: 'tag-tooltip', :data => {:toggle=>"tooltip"}, 'data-original-title' => get_icon_tooltip(get_icon_hash).html_safe, 'data-placement' => 'top' %>
```

Now, despite the html being the same for the icons

```
<i class="icon-off icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-info-sign icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-warning-sign icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-download-alt icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-list-alt icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> = SomeText
```

the end result is HTML with unescaped '<' and '>' characters.

```
<a class="tag-tooltip" data-original-title="<i class="icon-off icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-info-sign icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-warning-sign icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-download-alt icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-list-alt icon-white"></i> = SomeText<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> = SomeText" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#">First</a>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: My first thought is why you escape characters? Rails does that for you.. You can just wrap the quotes in single quotes and then reproduce HTML using the .html_safe method...

Comment: When I look at source, all of the angle brackets enclosed in the working string are escaped. When I look at the broken tag, none of the brackets are escaped. Regardless, I wrapped the `get_icon_tooltip` returned string in single quotes, and same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `html_safe` on your helper ? This will cause the unescaped characters.

Can you replace :

```
get_icon_tooltip(get_icon_hash).html_safe
```

by

```
get_icon_tooltip(get_icon_hash)
```

Comment: Sonofa. Why will this cause unescaped characters? I'm new to Ruby and Rails, but I assumed if I called html_safe on a helper method that returned a string that it would provide an html_safe string.

Comment: ``html_safe`` is used to tell rails that a string is safe and can be displayed unescaped.

By default, rails will automatically escape strings you pass to such helpers in order to avoid xss attacks. 

In your case, since the value you want to pass in data-original-title contains html tags, it will collide.